# Condtionally contenation of pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with the following data:

```
text                                                             Category
This is my first line. then there is more text                   Catergory 1
This is is second line. Additional text here                     Catergory 1, Catergory 2
This is the third line without any entries in Subject Column    
This is the fourth line. How about adding more                   Category 2
This is the fifth line. More text here                           Category 3
More text goes here for category2                                Category 2
```

I want text column concatenated by Category. Row2 has both categeory1 and 2 and hence should appear in the concatenated text for category1 as well category2. There are rows which have no category assigned as well.
output should be of the format:

```
Category 1          This is my first line. then there is more text. This is is second line. Additional text here
Category 2          This is is second line. Additional text here This is the fourth line. How about adding more More text goes here. More text goes here for category2
Category 3          This is the fifth line. More text here
```

Appreciate the help
thanks

Answer (score 1):

First split category column by commas into lists. Then explode. 
Groupby then and aggregate with str.join. Groupby preserves order, so no need to worry here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text' : ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'], 'Category' : ['c1', 'c1', 'c2, c1', 'c2']})

df.Category = df.Category.str.split('\s*,\s*')

df = df.explode('Category')

df.groupby('Category')['text'].agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

Category
c1    first second third
c2          third fourth
```